# Font from origin as been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy on multiple websites magento

Tags: magento-1.9, websites, .htaccess, fonts

I have created two websites using one magento installation, like:

1. **abc.com** (original)
2. **xyz.com** (second domain)

Both are working fine except the fonts issue I got on sub domain (second website). Error is:

> Font from origin 'abc.com' has been blocked from loading by
>   Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xyz.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access.

I have add the following code to `.htaccess` of main site but not working.

`.htaccess` code:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "xyz.com"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(svg|ttf|otf|eot|woff|woff2)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: try with Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: @MineshPatel i already tried that one if you look on my code.thanks

Comment: @MahmoodRehman, Have you found any solution for this?